# Finding the relation between row sums of a regular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework assignment which is:
You have a matrix which is regular ($ A * A' = I$ ), and the sum of each row = $C$.
Prove that the sum of each row in $A'$ are equal ( $= D$ ).
And then find the relation between $C$ and $D$.

I am having trouble with this question - could someone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: What does $A'$ mean? Is that the transpose of $A$?

Comment: The Inverse of $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be the all-ones vector. Then $Av$ is the all-$C$ vector, and $A'Av=Iv=v$. 
But also $A'Av=A'(Av)$. So $A'(Av)=v$, and $Av$ is the all-$C$ vector; what does that tell you about the row sums in $A'$?

Comment: Great :) Thanks alot